# Colorbox can not work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, magento, popup, colorbox

I have a popup by using colorbox, it's normally working on FF and IE 7+, but it's can not load the content of the static block.
[image]

My source code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function defaultPopup(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var direct = '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('popup')->toHtml();?>';
    if(direct){
        jQuery('#popup_home').colorbox({
            html:direct,
            maxHeight:jQuery(window).height(),
            open:true,
            overlayClose:false
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="popup_home" style="display:none">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('popup')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Do you have FIrebug installed? What does it tells?

Comment: Nothing, but on firebug of chrome, the content of this popup can load the content (an image), and it have been listed, but I don't know why the popup can not load on screen.

Comment: Meaning in DOM content is loaded, but it is not displayed? Might be some CSS logic error?

Comment: Yes. But why it's not display?

Comment: If you inspect popup content does display:none removed or can you remove it while inspecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this locally? Colorbox uses Ajax and Chrome doesn't allow Ajax requests locally.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Answer (score 0):

put the width and height attributes and the colorbox will work